# Copying a range from a container to another container

Tags: c#, containers

I have a generic container which has array access. I want to copy a range (elements 3 to 10, for instance) into another container (in this case a list).

I can iterate over the container, but I was hoping for something more elegant, and possibly faster.

Any ideas?

Comment: If your target container was also an array, Array.Copy would potentially be faster https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 Given the target is a list, I believe iterating is the best that you can do.

Comment: Array.Copy only copies from the first element. Is there a way of fooling it into thinking the nth element is the first?

Comment: so, what *is* your container?

Comment: @SimonParker: Array.Copy has an overload that can start at the Nth source index, copy to the Mth target index for a total of L elements https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5s0whfd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @EricJ., thanks for that. I missed that overload.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your "container" implements `IEnumerable`, you can use LINQ:

```
var list = container.Skip(3).Take(7).ToList();
```

There won't be anything *faster* than iteration if you want to end up with a standard `List<T>` instance.

Comment: That is such a great answer. I can't use it, as my container doesn't implement IEnumerable, but I like the answer so much I may have to fix this.